# Iterating through array gives full array of items at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to iterate through a set of records. However, at the end of the iteration, rails displays the full array.

```
<%= @portfolio_item.technologies.each do |technology| %>
  <p><%= technology.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

**What shows up in the browser**
[image]

Comment: When asking a question, please post actual code rather than screenshots.

Comment: Does anybody have a dupe link handy? I know that this exact same question has been asked and answered dozens of times already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this line

`<%= @portfolio_item.technologies.each do |technology| %>`

with this

`<% @portfolio_item.technologies.each do |technology| %>`

`<%= %>` will evaluate the expression and returns the array.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the quick response. Will accept as answer after 12 mins.